# Find operator can't go up in directory?

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to list all files of a directory that not exist in another.

And the script tells me:
`find: ‘ (...) /nanorc/../original/*’: No such file or directory`

Where is the problem? Thanks!

Code:

```sh
# todo: list all files that isn't in original folder
# get a file in nanorc folder
# try to find it in the ../original folder
# if there isn't, list it.

cd nanorc/
for file in *; do
  [ -e "$file" ] || continue

#  if [ -z $(find "$(pwd)/../original/*" -name "$file") ]; then
  if [ -z $(find $(pwd)/../original/* -name "$file") ]; then
    lite=`printf "%s %s" "$lite" "$file"`
  fi

done
cd ..

echo "$lite
```

Notes:

- The script must be POSIX complaint.
- I tried various variations of find, like: "../original", "../original/*",...
- I don't want to create files; the script should populate one variable after the checks.

**Solution:**
Just put out the "".

Comment: What should `[ -z $(find "$(pwd)/../original/*" -name "$file") ]` this check? `list all files that isn't in original folder` - if you want to do that, find all files in one folder, find all files in another folder, sort both list of files and extract entries with `comm`.

Comment: @KamilCuk That checks if there is output of find (normally the filename). And I don't want to create files.

Comment: Why do you need `find`? Are you searching subfolders too?

Comment: And btw the error is stemming from here -> `"$(pwd)/../original/*"`, no pathname expansions are performed on quoted strings

Comment: @oguzismail I just use find to don't use ls.

Comment: @oguzismail your last comment worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a file exists use `test -e`.

```
if [ ! -e "../original/$file" ]; then
    echo "File ../original/$file does not exists" 
fi
```

Path are by default searched in current working directory, there is no need to use `$(pwd)`.

The error in your script came from `"$(pwd)/../original/*"` - the `*` is inside `"` so it does not expand. You could change it to `"../original/"*`, but because `find` works recursively, just `find ../original`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this, but the echo/error after the test isn't necessary (in this case).